# SVG export from Illustrator CC distorts paths

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, cc-2014

I'm trying to create some icons to add to the Glyphicons library.

I've created them using the pen tool (shapes) in Adobe Illustrator CC, they're ultra-basic. As PNG, or EPS they export fine. Unfortunately I need the SVG export to use with Glyphicons.

When I export to SVG, the shapes seem to move around. At very least they don't remain as they appear on my screen.

How can I get them to appear as they do in illustrator?

This is a PNG from inside illustrator.
[image]

This is a PNG from preview, this is the SVG.
[image: The shapes are clearly arranged differently.]

Clearly the shapes are becoming misaligned after the export, are there any obvious reasons for this? All my export settings are set as default.

Comment: could you give some detailed info on how the geometry is made any chance for a image where all objects are selected to see the anchors. Also for round numbers use grid

Comment: Thanks for raising question! I was suffering from the same

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Change "Decimal places" to 3 in the "SVG Options" dialog appearing when saving as SVG:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's work like charm!!! Cool man

Comment: THANK YOU!!! Why on earth would Adobe think 1 decimal place was all you needed?!

Answer (score 2):

This is a common error in .SVG file .. that's because hard curves (curves made with only two anchors and long handles) this cant not be rendered good by the browser.

The best thing to do is to divide your path into smaller segments, specially around the anchor that have the problem.

Just go to `Object > Path > Add Anchor Points`

Comment: That didn't seem to have any effect at all. Also, I read somewhere that you should try to keep the minimum possible number of anchor points to help with load times for mobile rendering of SVG. Is that total nonsense, or is it a kind of balancing act?

Answer (score 0):

I tend to get the best results from my SVG saves when the coordinates of my objects have clean decimal values. For example, an object at X = 100.452 would be moved to X = 100.5. I've experienced slight movements similar to your issue when leaving objects at coordinates with messy fractional parts.

Comment: Interesting, how do you achieve that. Must be a right pain to position stuff so accurately?

Comment: @AndrewPeachey It's not very difficult. Simply click on the object, and click the up or down arrows next to the position to make it round to the next number.

Comment: Ah. Of course.
Makes sense. Cheers, will investigate.

Comment: If you're animating an SVG this speeds thing up to, keeping them on a pixel. Its harder for computers to crunch floating point numbers. And harder for displays to guess if it should 1 pixel to the left or the right.

Answer (score 0):

Solution Found.

This is clearly not the best, cleanest most beautiful solution but it works exceptionally well.

My Process:
1. Draw the icon in Illustrator
2. Save out as .ai file
3. Open .ai in OSX iDraw
4. Export to SVG from iDraw

Simple solution:
1. Draw the icon in iDraw
2. Export to SVG from iDraw

I hope this helps other folks out

Answer (score 0):

I've been having troubles exporting too, and tried:

`File`> `Save as`

instead of:

`File`> `Export`> `Export as`.

And that seemed to do the trick!

Answer (score -1):

As i discover this trouble apperrs only if you export "selected only". When exporter do not see borders (page) it make something wrong with curves.