# SVG Export in Corel Distorted

Tags: svg, export, corel-draw, distort

Hi Guys I know a similar question has been asked for Illustrator but the problem mentioned was mild in comparison. Some of the exports that I am making from CorelDraw X7 to SVG are getting distorted, and i'm not taling about the bitmap render i'm talking about the whole file.

[image: A screenshot of what the artwork looks like while working on it in corel]

[image: A screenshot of when i open the exported SVG in Chrome or Edge]

[image: A screenshot of when i open the exported SVG back in Corel]

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54161/svg-export-from-illustrator-cc-distorts-paths

Comment: Check this link for answer http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54161/svg-export-from-illustrator-cc-distorts-paths

Answer (score 0):

Well I still don't know what went wrong but I restarted corel and the problem disappeared. Hope that works for you if you face this problem.

Comment: so you posted the question before even trying to restart the software?