# How to export SVG in illustrator, and make object doesn't messy?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, svg, icon, stroke

I've been struggling to create an icon in illustrator and convert it to SVG but the result is my SVG file becomes a messy object after I export it into SVG.

Can someone explain me why? I'm already trying different export setting but the issue still same.

[image: svg export icon]
[image: 1px stroke arrow svg]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for: [SVG export from Illustrator CC distorts paths](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54161/svg-export-from-illustrator-cc-distorts-paths)

Obviously we won't be able to see what paths you're using, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, the problem has been answered. The problem is in the decimal setting when I export the file, in previous, I set the decimal number on 2, then I change it to 3 and the export SVG file became better.